# Protocol get Java URL

Tags: java, url, google-api, protocols

I'm trying to get a JSON format of all the websites found when querying google.

### Code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Vlad on 19/03/14.
 */
public class Query {   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
        String arg;
            arg = "random";

        URL url = new URL("GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=" + arg);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8");

    int ch;
            while((ch = reader.read()) != -1){
    System.out.print(ch);
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("This ain't good");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }    
}
```

### Exception:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCS26VtzuCs7bEpC821X_l0io_PHc4-8tY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete the `GET` at the beginning ;)

You should replace your code by :

`URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCS26VtzuCs7bEpC821X_l0io_PHc4-8tY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=" + arg);`

Url never start by `GET` or `POST`or anything like that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Urls are supposed to start with a protocol for transfer and `GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCS26VtzuCs7bEpC821X_l0io_PHc4-8tY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=random` is starting with `GET`, that is why the exception is received.

Change it to `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCS26VtzuCs7bEpC821X_l0io_PHc4-8tY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=random`